# Is there an objective reference for productivity?

Tags: productivity

Is there an objective reference for productivity?

What kind?

Are there shortcomings?

Something that puzzles me is that often people see it in hours spent, but this clearly does not equate to productivity linearly. Except in some "linear fields" like where you can actually count the amount of things.

Comment: No. Move on, next question please.

Comment: What does productivity mean to you? Number of widgets built? Amount of revenue generated? Number of hours spent? Amount of innovation (whatever that mean)?

Comment: @SethR Well perhaps it then depends on what goals have been set.

Comment: @mavavilj absolutely. So what are your goals? We can't answer this question until we know what you are after.

Comment: @SethR To criticize claims laid out about "productivity"?

Comment: @mavavilj I don't think there is an objective reference for that.

Comment: @SethR Then what's the purpose of measuring it?

Comment: @mavavilj that's what I'm asking you.

Comment: @SethR It's measured by some people, thus someone thinks it exists.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Then it's not objective if it's relative to a value decision.

Answer (score 3):

From a macroeconomic sense, productivity is generally defined as the ratio of GDP to hours worked. You could try and apply this to a company over time, with something like:

> Two months ago our staff worked 10,000 hours total and we made £500k revenue. Then we bought a new WidgetMaker 5000 machine, and the month after they only worked 9,000 hours but made £550k revenue - so our productivity has gone up.

You could also use to this t compare between companies - but it's a pretty crude metric.

Measuring employee productivity is usually done based on Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) - but exactly what these are is completely dependent on the role.

However, the problem with this approach is that as soon as you try and measure something *and the take action based on the results*, it stops being an accurate measure, because employees are incentivised to change their behaviour based on your actions. For example, if you have a KPI for "number of support tickets closed", you incentivise staff to close easy tickets and to rush their fixes - which could end up having a negative effect overall.

Accurately measuring productivity is very difficult, and before you can even think about doing it you need to be absolutely clear on what "good" looks like for your employees.

Comment: Even GDP is a poor metric, because the ratio of goods and services to money is not fixed. The housing contribution to GDP may go up just because landlords are charging more money for the exact same houses. That doesn't mean there was more productivity, just more overpricing.

Comment: @user253751 that's true - but then any attempt to try and summarise an entire economy into one number is going to be a crude and poor metric.

Comment: To wit, a common (or used to be common) KPI in software development is Lines of Code (LOC). Is a developer who writes 1000 LOC in a day more productive than one who only wrote 200? What if the developer who wrote the 200 LOC was working on a really hard problem and it just took them most of the day to figure it out? What if those 1000 LOC really could have been compressed down to 100 by a more skilled developer? LOC will tell you how much a developer materially output, but does not tell you how useful that output is.

Comment: @SethR And of course, the famous anecdote of Bill Atkinson making a huge performance improvement by rewriting some core functions in Quickdraw, which resulted in -2000 LoC, and the metric quickly being scrapped.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an objective reference for productivity.  However, depending on the frame of reference, its value will change.  For example, your company wants its workers to make 100 widgets a day.  If every worker is meeting that quota, then you are objectively meeting 100% productivity.  However, if the workers finish the 100 in 4 hours and slack off the rest of the day, then their personal productivity is at 50% per hour.  Productivity, will take on different values based on the parameters you set for it.

Answer (score 0):

### Of course there are objective measures, but they may or may not apply to the specific work you are part of.

Workers performing physical tasks can be measured versus objective Time Motion Analysis standards.  These involve how long it takes to physically perform activities based on time studies.  Locate an object, walk towards it, move arm, grasp, reposition, pick up, place in container, etc.

Almost all factories will have some form of productivity measure, if only labor hours versus factory output.

**Knowledge workers** are harder to measure, but there are measures we can put in place. Some measures will be better than others at being worthwhile to measure.  Examples include:

- Burn Rate versus deliverables for contractors
- lines of code delivered per effort hour
- QA scenarios tested per effort hour
- patients seen per hour
- Agile sprint activities closed per effort hour

Note that some of these can drive behaviors that are counter to actual business goals, and some can be so broad as to penalize workers who perform complex tasks ("Mary always gives me the hardest tasks!").

Comment: "Note that some of these can drive behaviors that are counter to actual business goals, and some can be so broad as to penalize workers who perform complex tasks" - Lines of code / hour is a good example that will drive the code quality straight to garbage if used as KPI :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most objective, in a business sense, are financial measures of productivity -- such as revenue generated.

Works better for some things (like sales work) than others. Good at team level or project level. Hard for individuals, for anything with multi year impact (because orgs want feedback quarterly), and most of all, hard for something with a preventive function, like investment in quality.